# Función computada de VUE no actualiza los valores en la VISTA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Buenas que tal? Gracias por tomarse un momento para leer mi consulta.

Tecnologias y frameworks que estoy usando: `Javascript`, `Vue.JS`, `QUASAR.dev`

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un table que carga desde un array de productos. Debajo, un bloque que devuelve la suma de la propiedad "total_precio" para cada uno de estos productos. tal cual sería una caja registradora.

Cuando la web carga por primera vez mi función computada "totalCaja" me devuelve la suma total de los artículos en el `<table></table>` sin problema alguno. pero cuando cambio el valor del "precio total" una vez que ya cargo la vista. el bloque en vez de actualizarme el valor total correspondiente a la suma de la propiedad "total_caja" para todos los objetos, me devuelve "0.00". por consola no recibo error alguno.

fragmento de INDEX.VUE (template) y Fragmento del `<script></script>` index.vue

```js
<script>
  export default {
  name: 'PageIndex',
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'name',
          required: true,
          label: 'Nombre de producto/Servicio',
          align: 'left',
          field: 'name',
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: 'Precio_Total',
          required: true,
          label: 'Nombre de producto/Servicio',
          align: 'left',
          field: Precio_Total,
          sortable: true
        }
      ],
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Chocolate',
          Precio_Total: 17
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totalCaja() {
      let total_caja =  parseFloat(this.data.reduce((sum, value) => (typeof value.Precio_Total == "number" ? sum + value.Precio_Total : sum), 0)).toFixed(2);
      return total_caja
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.11/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.11/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<template>
      <q-table class="my-sticky-header-table"
        color="primary"
        style="height:200%;"
        title="Detalle de productos/Servicios"
        dense
        :data="data"
        :columns="columns"
        row-key="name"
        flat
        bordered
        hide-bottom>
          <template v-slot:body="props">
            <q-tr :props="props">
              <q-td key="name" :props="props">
                {{ props.row.name }}
                <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.name" title="Editar Nombre">
                  <q-input v-model="props.row.name" dense autofocus counter />
                </q-popup-edit>
              </q-td>
            </q-tr> 
          </template>
    </q-table>
  <div v-text="totalCaja"></div>
</template>
```

Aguardo sus comentarios, gracias

Comment: Si sacas ese condicional dentro del redeuce, que sucede?

Comment: era ese el problema!, sos un genio. gracias amigo. responde a la pregunta para marcarlo como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés un problema cuando asignas el valor a la variable `total_caja`.

```
let total_caja =  parseFloat(this.data.reduce((sum, value) => (typeof value.Precio_Total == "number" ? sum + value.Precio_Total : sum), 0)).toFixed(2);
```

Por partes:

- Tenés un `array` de objetos, y querés sumar los valores de una propiedad de esos objetos. Y para eso utilizas [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), que podría ser simplemente:

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate',
    Precio_Total: 17
  },
  {
    name: 'Caramelo',
    Precio_Total: 10
  },
];
let total = array1.reduce((acumulador, objeto) => { 
  return acumulador + objeto.Precio_Total; 
}, 0);
console.log('total', total);
```

- Si querés cubrirte por si uno de los valores viene como `string`, en vez de `number`. Puedes agregarle ese `parsefloat` en el momento que obtienes la propiedad del objeto a sumar:

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate',
    Precio_Total: 17
  },
  {
    name: 'Caramelo',
    Precio_Total: "10"
  },
];
let total = array1.reduce((acumulador, objeto) => { 
  return acumulador + parseFloat(objeto.Precio_Total); 
}, 0);
console.log('total', total);
```

De esa manera, te aseguras de que vas a sumar número con número.

- Finalmente para "redondear" el resultado a 2 dígitos decimales, le aplicas el `toFixed(2)` (te devolverá un string, pero para renderizarlo no importa el tipo de dato):

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate',
    Precio_Total: 17
  },
  {
    name: 'Caramelo',
    Precio_Total: "10"
  },
];
let total = array1.reduce((acumulador, objeto) => { 
  return acumulador + parseFloat(objeto.Precio_Total); 
}, 0).toFixed(2);
console.log('total', total);
```

En un snippet de Vue:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    data: [],
    item: {
      name: 'Chocolate',
      Precio_Total: 17
    },
  },
  computed: {
    totalCaja() {
      return this.data.reduce((acumulador, objeto) => { 
          return acumulador + parseFloat(objeto.Precio_Total); 
      }, 0).toFixed(2);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addData() {
      this.data.push(this.item)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.addData();
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <button @click="addData">Agregar</button>
  <h3>Total Caja: {{totalCaja}}</h3>
</div>
```